# How to get the char at a given position of a string in shell script?

Tags: shell, shell-script

How to get the char at a given position of a string in shell script?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In bash with "Parameter Expansion" ${parameter:offset:length}

```bsh
$ var=abcdef
$ echo ${var:0:1}
a
$ echo ${var:3:1}
d
```

The same parameter expansion can be used to assign a new variable:

```bsh
$ x=${var:1:1}
$ echo $x
b
```

Edit: Without parameter expansion (not very elegant, but that's what came to me first)

```
$ charpos() { pos=$1;shift; echo "$@"|sed 's/^.\{'$pos'\}\(.\).*$/\1/';}
$ charpos 8 what ever here
r
```

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion has more details

Comment: Not POSIX apparently: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

Comment: You can also set the offset 'from end' like so `echo ${var: -2:1}`

Comment: That syntax comes from ksh93 and is also supported by `zsh` and `mksh`.

Answer (score 13):

Alternative to parameter expansion is `expr substr`

```
substr STRING POS LENGTH
    substring of STRING, POS counted from 1
```

For example:

```
$ expr substr hello 2 1
e
```

Comment: cool, should have checked expr more thoroughly.

Comment: While this appears to work with the expr from GNU coreutils, `substr` is not included in the expr from FreeBSD, NetBSD or OS X. This isn't a portable solution.

Comment: @ghoti, note that `substr` is not originally a GNU extension. The original implementation of `expr` came from PWB Unix in the late 70s and had `substr` (but not `:`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks for adding historical perspective. :)  While I'm pretty sure PWB usage isn't relevant to the OP, it's always fun to track features and changes through the decades. GNU tends to be many people's default, but in general, I think I'd avoid using options that aren't clearly [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html), and are known to be missing from major unices.

Answer (score 11):

**`cut -c`**

If the variable does not contain newlines you can do:

```
myvar='abc'
printf '%s\n' "$myvar" | cut -c2
```

outputs:

```
b
```

`awk substr` is another POSIX alternative that works even if the variable has newlines:

```
myvar="$(printf 'a\nb\n')" # note that the last newline is stripped by
                           # the command substitution
awk -- 'BEGIN {print substr (ARGV[1], 3, 1)}' "$myvar"
```

outputs:

```
b
```

`printf '%s\n'` is to avoid problems with escape characters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40423558/895245 e.g.:

```
myvar='\n'
printf '%s\n' "$myvar" | cut -c1
```

outputs `\` as expected.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405611/extracting-first-two-characters-of-a-string-shell-scripting

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: `printf '%s' "$myvar" | cut -c2` is not POSIX as the output of `printf` is not text unless `$myvar` ends in a newline character. It otherwise assumes the variable doesn't contain newline characters as `cut` cuts *each line* of its input.

Comment: The `awk` one would be more efficient and reliable with `awk -- 'BEGIN {print substr (ARGV[1], 2, 1)}' "$myvar"`

Comment: Note that with current versions of GNU `cut`, that doesn't work for multi-byte characters (same for mawk or busybox awk)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for the points. I didn't understand what you mean in the first one: do you mean that `printf 'abc '| cut -c2` is wrong because no `\n` (this I don't know about), or that the command will fail if myvar has newlines (this I agree)?

Comment: The behaviour of `cut` is unspecified if the input is not text (though `cut` implementations are required to handle lines or arbitrary length). The output of `printf abc` is not *text* as it doesn't end in a newline character. In practice depending on the implementation, if you pipe that to `cut -c2`, you get either `b`, `b<newline>` or nothing at all. You'd need `printf 'abc\n' | cut -c2` to get a behaviour specified by POSIX (that's required to output `b<newline>`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah OK, awesome, I wasn't aware that POSIX defined what a "text file" is! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446237/what-conditions-must-be-met-for-a-file-to-be-a-text-file-as-defined-by-posix

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` or `yash`, you'd use:

```
$ text='€$*₭£'
$ printf '%s\n' "${text[3]}"
*
```

(in `zsh`, you can shorten it to `printf '%s\n' $text[3]`).

Answer (score 2):

This is a portable POSIX shell variant, which only uses builtins.
First a oneliner, than a better readable function.
It uses "parameter expansion" explained here:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02

```
#!/bin/sh
x(){ s=$1;p=$2;i=0;l=${#s};while i=$((i+1));do r=${s#?};f=${s%"$r"};s=$r;case $i in $p)CHAR=$f&&return;;$l)return 1;;esac;done;}

x ABCDEF 3   # output substring at pos 3
echo $CHAR   # output is 'C'
```

Here the oneliner explained.

```
#!/bin/sh

string_get_pos()
{
  local string="$1"             # e.g. ABCDEF
  local pos="$2"                # e.g. 3
  local rest first i=0
  local length="${#string}"     # e.g. 6

  while i=$(( i + 1 )); do
    rest="${string#?}"          # e.g.  BCDEF
    first=${string%"$rest"}     # e.g. A
    string="$rest"

    case "$i" in
      $pos) export CHAR="$first" && return 0 ;;
      $length) return 1 ;;
    esac
  done
}

string_get_pos ABCDEF 3
echo $CHAR                # output is 'C'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cut command. To get the 3rd postion:

```
echo "SAMPLETEXT" | cut -c3
```

Check this link http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/02/cut-command-in-unix-linux-examples.html

(**Advanced cases**) However, modifying IFS is also a good thing, especially when your input might have spaces. In that case alone, use the one below

```
saveifs=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
echo "SAMPLETEXT" | cut -c3
IFS=$saveifs
```

Comment: I can't see how `IFS` would come into play in the code that you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

shell cut - print specific range of characters or given part from a string

#method1) using bash

```
 str=2020-08-08T07:40:00.000Z
 echo ${str:11:8}
```

#method2) using cut

```
 str=2020-08-08T07:40:00.000Z
 cut -c12-19 <<< $str
```

#method3) when working with awk

```
 str=2020-08-08T07:40:00.000Z
 awk '{time=gensub(/.{11}(.{8}).*/,"\\1","g",$1); print time}' <<< $str
```