# Search for three consecutive newlines?

Tags: grep, search

I know that squeezing multiple blank lines can be done using `cat -s` (and squeezing all blank lines can be done using `tr -s '\n'`), but I'm curious how to *search* for this condition in a stream of input.

I thought that `stream-of-input | grep -qz $'\n\n\n'` would do it, but it doesn't.

Is there a way to do this search with simple tools?

In other words, read input, and exit with a zero status if three consecutive bytes are newline characters, or exit with nonzero status if EOF is reached without finding three consecutive newline characters.

Comment: GNU `grep -Pzq '\n\n\n'` seems to work... not sure the whys and wherefores

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tr` to transform the stream into one you can grep normally:

```
stream | tr 'x\n' '\0x' | grep -qz xxx
```

This turns all `x` bytes into null bytes, and all linefeed bytes into `x`s, which can be grepped out as usual. That is, it moves one step along the path linefeed -> x -> null, so a sequence of three linefeeds will now be a sequence of three `x`s, and no other `x` bytes will occur (they will have become nulls terminating lines for the `grep`).

---

This works [with POSIX `tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html), but `grep -z` is an extension. You *may* not need it - the separation behaviour isn't required here - and most `grep`s will handle binary data, but [POSIX `grep` is only required to work on text files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) so you're going to be depending on an extension one way or another.

If your real data is a text file, or just doesn't depend on binary-safe behaviour, you can probably survive on just

```
stream | tr 'x\n' '\nx' | grep -q xxx
```

- that is, just swapping the two bytes. This is *nearly* POSIX-compatible, but will likely work in practice just about anywhere (the issue is that the final line [won't be terminated correctly, so it's not a text file, so `grep` isn't strictly required to accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446241/73093)).

One possible issue in either case is that a file with no existing `x` bytes will be considered as one very long line, which may exceed the limits your `grep` implementation will handle. Choosing another expected-to-be-common byte may work around that.

I was surprised that your original `grep -qz $'\n\n\n'` command didn't work, but it had a false-*positive* problem for me - it seemed to behave like `grep -qz ''` and always matched. I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: Actually, `grep -z` is unneeded.  `stream | tr 'x\n' '\nx' | grep -q xxx` works perfectly and is POSIX.  Thanks!

Comment: There is one really technical point that makes it still certainly non-POSIX - the final line won't have a terminating line feed, so it's strictly speaking a text file and `grep` isn't required to accept it - but for all practical purposes it should be fine. `| (tr 'x\n' '\nx' ; printf '\n') | ` *is* fully compliant up to `x` being too infrequent.

Answer (score 2):

`lex` (or `flex`) could handle this, e.g. the following saved to the file `tresn.l` with the extra rules mostly to prevent the default output to stdout (you may want that?)

```
%%
\n\n\n  { exit(0); }
<<EOF>> { exit(1); }
\n\n    { ; }
\n      { ; }
.       { ; }
%%
```

compiles up with implicit `make` rules plus pulling in of `libfl*`

```
$ CFLAGS=-lfl make tresn
lex  -o lex.tresn.c tresn.l
cc -lfl   -o tresn lex.tresn.c  -ll
rm -f lex.tresn.c
$ printf "\n\n" | ./tresn ; echo $?
1
$ printf "\n\n\n" | ./tresn ; echo $?
0
```

on some systems you may need to add `-L/opt/local/lib` or such to `CFLAGS` or also `LDFLAGS` if `libfl*` is hiding off under some ports or package system outside of the vendor compile space.