# Why does `ssh-add` not show my GPG authentication key?

Tags: ssh, gpg-agent

I tried to set up an authentication subkey with GPG for authentication against SSH servers, following [this instruction set](https://opensource.com/article/19/4/gpg-subkeys-ssh).  Everything seems to work so far, but `ssh-add -l` does not show any keys:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

Also I cannot log in to servers where I put my public key.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that `gpg-agent` is picky about line endings in `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol`.  Specifically the line with the key ID needs to end with a newline, having the end of file there is not sufficient.

After adding a newline to the `sshcontrol` config file, `ssh-add -l` shows the key correctly.

Comment: Is this the solution to your post? Just wondering since this sounds like a comment to me, and you don't mention if this make `ssh-add -l` show the wanted output but I don't mind if i were to be wrong here :)

Comment: Thank you for your remark, @NordineLotfi, I amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: Having a newline at the end is what makes it a line (and, by extension, the file a text file) [by definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446241/70524).