# Find and replace a multi line text file in another multi line text file

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I fought with it for so long but I am now completely out of ideas. Maybe someone here will be able to help me. Here is what I want to achieve:

`file_1.txt`:

```
# Some comment
some_variable="test"
some other things

# Marker

More things!@#$%^
```

`file_2.txt`:

```
# Marker
# Some other comment
other_variable_1="test"

# Some totally other comment
other_variable_2="test"
```

I want to insert `file_2.txt` into `file_1.txt` in place of `# Marker` and later I want to reverse this process.

Final file `file_1.txt`:

```
# Some comment
some_variable="test"
some other things

# Marker
# Some other comment
other_variable_1="test"

# Some totally other comment
other_variable_2="test"

More things!@#$%^
```

Problem is, both files are multiline and contains various special characters. I would also like to have both of those files in variables.

I tried various things, sed, perl and awk. Nothing worked for me. This is my closest attempt I think:

```
perl -pi -e 'chomp if eof' file_2.txt
marker_var="# Marker"
file_2_var=$(tr '\n' '\f' <file_2.txt)

sed -e "s|$marker_var|$file_2_var| tr '\f' '\n'" file_1.txt
```

I say closest because it it still not working. I tried to combine various answers from stackexchange but It throws error about not properly ended `s`. I suspected that it is because of final `\n` new line in file so I tried to delete it with perl command but it didn't work.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Note that text files [_require_ a trailing newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446237/22222) by definition.

Comment: Not clear how you plan to *reverse* the insertion once completed. Is there a marker at the end of `File2.txt` that you plan on tracking?

Comment: Regarding `I would also like to have both of those files in variables.` - that's usually a bad idea that means you are pursuing the wrong solution to some problem.

Comment: When you say `later I want to reverse this process` - that would mean removing the contents of `file_2.txt` from the output of running the merge command and it's not at all clear how you could do that robustly. Do you actually just mean `later I want to reverse the order of the input files and do the same thing`?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have perl, then do perl all the way:

```
open(f1,"<file_1.txt");
open(f2,"<file_2.txt");
open(out,">new_file_1.txt");

while(<f1>) {
   last if /# Marker/;
   print out;
}
print out while(<f2>);
print out while(<f1>);

close(out);
close(f1);
close(f2);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or I explained my problem in a poor way. I saved it as a perl script and I am running it from my shell script and I am getting printed a lot of `GLOB`s and after that my program fails. Why is that?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be filehandles, not references to them:
`print $h $_` vs `print h`.
Code corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Merging files with awk is actually trivial:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {if ($1 == "#" && $2 == "Marker") while((getline a<ARGV[2]) > 0) print a; else print}' file_1.txt file_2.txt > out
```

- `NR==FNR` Is an awk trick to ensure we operate only on the first file. Check this [answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481877/what-are-nr-and-fnr-and-what-does-nr-fnr-implyhttps://) on NR & FNR
- `{if ($1 == "#" && $2 == "Marker")else print}` : Parse the first file and output all line when `# Marker` is **not** found.
- `while((getline a<ARGV[2]) > 0) print a;` Parse the content of ARGV[2] (here it is file_2.txt) and output it.
- `> out` is a shell redirect and write the output of this command in the out file (and create the file if it does not exist.

The result :

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {if ($1 == "#" && $2 == "Marker") while((getline a<ARGV[2]) > 0) print a; else print}' file_1.txt file_2.txt
# Some comment
some_variable="test"
some other things

# Marker
# Some other comment
other_variable_1="test"

# Some totally other comment
other_variable_2="test"

More things!@#$%^
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ee '/Marker/{e cat file_2.txt' -e ';d}' file_1.txt
# Some comment
some_variable="test"
some other things

# Marker
# Some other comment
other_variable_1="test"

# Some totally other comment
other_variable_2="test"


More things!@#$%^
```

Comment: The `e` command seems to insert a shell command to the output, interesting. A GNU extension? But it doesn't show in the man page … where is a documentation? Anyhow, what is the advantage of `e echo` over the standard `r`?

Comment: @Philippos No advantage as far as I can tell, I just prefer to use it as it is more flexible than r allowing for more than just read operations. Your answer is essentially exactly the same as mine

Comment: Well, mine is portable and adds an explanation. My question was serious: Where can I find a documentation of the `e` command? Why is it not included in the man page? Since which version does it work? Are there any security concerns?

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
my $f1  =  open :r, 'Peksio1.txt';
my $f2  =  open :r, 'Peksio2.txt';
my $out =  open :w, 'Peksio_out.txt';

for ($f1.lines) {
  last if / ^ "#" \s Marker $ /;
  $out.put($_);
};

$out.put($_) for $f2.lines;
$out.put($_) for $f1.lines;

close($f1);
close($f2);
close($out);
```

Above is a direct translation of the Perl(5) answer posted by @White_Owl. The two source files are opened for `:r` reading, while the destination file is opened for `:w` writing. The keyword `for` is used to iterate over `lines` of the first file, breaking out of the loop with `last` when the full `Marker` line is encountered.

[Note: The `Marker` regex can be changed to make it more/less stringent. Also note: the `#` octothorpe must be double-quoted to be recognized as a literal character (backslashing won't work). This is probably due to the ability to add within-regex comments via `#`].

The destination file `$out` has `lines` (referenced as the `$_` topic variable) `put` into it, until no lines remain.

Sample Output:

```
# Some comment
some_variable="test"
some other things

# Marker
# Some other comment
other_variable_1="test"

# Some totally other comment
other_variable_2="test"


More things!@#$%^
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/101-basics
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple standard `sed` solution?

```
sed -e '/# Marker/{r file_2.txt' -e 'd;}' file_1.txt
```

The `r`ead command inserts a file without caring for special characters. Additionally, you need to `d`elete the duplicate `# Marker` line.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{new=new sep $0; sep=ORS; next} /# Marker/{$0=new} 1' file_2.txt file_1.txt
# Some comment
some_variable="test"
some other things

# Marker
# Some other comment
other_variable_1="test"

# Some totally other comment
other_variable_2="test"

More things!@#$%^
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{new=new sep $0; sep=ORS; next} /# Marker/{$0=new} 1' file_1.txt file_2.txt
# Some comment
some_variable="test"
some other things

# Marker

More things!@#$%^
# Some other comment
other_variable_1="test"

# Some totally other comment
other_variable_2="test"
```

Regarding the script in your question:

1. As soon as you do `tr '\n' '\f'` you no longer have a valid text file as it no longer contains the required terminating newline and so YMMV with what `sed` or any other text processing tool will do with it.
2. The process of mapping newlines to/from form-feeds would fail when your input contains form-feeds, as is used between functions in code that wants to force functions to start at the top of a new page when printed (or other similar text that requires page breaks at specific locations when printed).
3. You can't do `sed -e "s|$marker_var|$file_2_var|` because `file_2_var` could itself contain `|`s or backreferences like `&` or `\1` that sed would then interpret, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001.